# scala: overriding named parameter

Tags: scala

Given the code below

```
class Parent {
  def mth(p1: Int = 1, p2: Int = 2) = p1 + p2
}
class Child extends Parent{
  override def mth(p2: Int = 10, p1: Int = 20) = super.mth(p2, p1)
}
object Main {
  def main(args: String[]) = {
    val parentRefToChild: Parent = new Child
    println(parentRefToChild.mth(p1=1))   // 21
  }
}
```

The output is `21` but I think it should be `11`. And when inspecting the compiled .class file, I found that `parentRefToChild.mth(p1=1)` was compiled to `parentRefToChild.mth(1, parentRefToChild.mth$default$2())`. How could scala compiler behave this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem here is that you have changed sequence of parameters in `Child`:

```
override def mth(p2: Int = 10 , p1: Int = 20)
```

So generated synthetic methods for `mth` in `Child` class, will be like:

```
def mth$default$1 = 10 // generated method for p2 in Child
def mth$default$2 = 20 // generated method for p1 in Child
```

When you call `mth` on `Parent` class reference, static type checking is used to determine if parameter has default value or not. Here, static type checking will be done on `Parent` as `parentRefToChild` is of type `Parent`.

So, when `parentRefToChild.mth(p1=1)` is encountered, at this point compiler *does not* know that `parentRefToChild` is actually holding `Child` class instance. It just tries to match `mth`'s signature from `Parent` class. Now, here it sees that value of `p1` is provided but `p2` is missing and it has default value, it simply replaces `parentRefToChild.mth(p1=1)` with:

`parentRefToChild.mth(1, parentRefToChild.mth$default$2())`

Now at runtime, synthetic method `mth$default$2()` is picked from `Child` class (as `parentRefToChild` holds `Child`'s instance) which then turns into:

`parentRefToChild.mth(1, 20)`

Hence you get `21` as output.